# Updating an integer value using try-catch and showing it using a toast

Tags: java, android

I am trying to update `intdelay` by taking the value from an edittext and converting it into an integer as shown below, and I am using a toast to check the updated value of `intdelay`.

```
public static int intdelay=1000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    delayedttxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.delayedttxt);
    String delay=delayedttxt.getText().toString();       //this will get a string
    try{
        int intdelay = Integer.parseInt(delay);
   }catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception
    }

    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            flashLight.switchFlash();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"your integer is " + intdelay , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

but the `intdelay` value is not getting updated.
How I can solve that?

**Note:** I have to use the try-catch structure because otherwise the app crashes.

When I remove the try-catch, 
the code becomes as following:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        delayedttxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.delayedttxt);
        String delay=delayedttxt.getText().toString();
        final int intdelay = Integer.parseInt(delay);

        Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            flashLight.switchFlash();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"your integer is " + intdelay ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

and the logcat after crash as following:

```
08-22 16:13:05.866 17636-17636/de.nocnoc.clean.cleanlight I/RequestQueue: Repeating capture request set.
08-22 16:13:05.876 17636-17790/de.nocnoc.clean.cleanlight W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
08-22 16:13:05.876 17636-17790/de.nocnoc.clean.cleanlight W/LegacyRequestMapper: Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
08-22 16:13:06.866 17636-17636/de.nocnoc.clean.cleanlight I/RequestQueue: Repeating capture request cancelled.
08-22 16:13:06.866 17636-17636/de.nocnoc.clean.cleanlight I/RequestQueue: Repeating capture request set.
08-22 16:13:06.894 17636-17790/de.nocnoc.clean.cleanlight W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
08-22 16:13:06.894 17636-17790/de.nocnoc.clean.cleanlight W/LegacyRequestMapper: Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
08-22 16:19:51.367 19348-19348/de.nocnoc.clean.cleanlight W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/de.nocnoc.clean.cleanlight-2/lib/arm
08-22 16:19:51.404 19348-19348/de.nocnoc.clean.cleanlight D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-22 16:19:51.414 19348-19348/de.nocnoc.clean.cleanlight E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: de.nocnoc.clean.cleanlight, PID: 19348
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.nocnoc.clean.cleanlight/de.nocnoc.clean.flashlight.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                                at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                                at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                                                                                at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                                                at de.nocnoc.clean.flashlight.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
08-22 16:19:53.050 19348-19348/de.nocnoc.clean.cleanlight I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19348 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you share the logcat of the crash?

Comment: The fact that the app crashes without the try-catch should tell you that something is wrong in the line where you parse the delay string and assing it to intdelay. That's the problem: your intdelay value is not updated because an exception is thrown when parsing the string.

Comment: I shared the non try-crash code and the logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `intdelay` only in `onCreate`, you should read the value of edit text every time before displaying the toast. In other way inside `onClickListener`. Initially the edit text will not have any value in it and so `Integer.parseInt` call will `throw` `NumberFormatException`.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         String delay = delayedttxt.getText().toString();
         int intdelay = 0;
         try{
             intdelay = Integer.parseInt(delay);
         } catch(NumberFormatException ex){
           e.printStackTrace();// Never swallow exception
         }
         flashLight.switchFlash();
         Toast.makeText("Initial Delay : " + intdelay , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: it worked perfectly after deleting `e.printStackTrace();`, is it important or not?

Comment: @Ans Yes. You can also log the exception if you don't want to print stack trace. `NumberFormatException` is runtime exception, if you are sure that `String delay`  will never be anything which *can not* be parsed to number you can happily remove try-catch block.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because before you set any value in edittext , delay gets initialized. Move this line

```
String delay=delayedttxt.getText().toString();
```

inside the onclick method , like this -

```
 Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    String delay=delayedttxt.getText().toString();
        flashLight.switchFlash();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"your integer is " + intdelay , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Then try again

Answer (score 0):

You should put

```
String delay=delayedttxt.getText().toString();       //this will get a string
try{
    int intdelay = Integer.parseInt(delay);
}catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception
}
```

Inside the onclicklistener
It is throwing NumberFormatException because you are parsing a empty string returned by getText method and
It won't require try catch after doing that

Comment: Illegal start of type

Comment: Did you put this in onclick method